# Select randomly a range of rows in database

Tags: sqlite, xamarin

I am a novice in Xamarin.

I am looking for a way to select a range of data in my table.

I want to do something like this with Sqlite in Xamarin :

```
"SELECT Word.ID FROM MyWords WHERE Word.ID BETWEEN 10 AND 15"
```

Here is my methode  I do not know how to do the "between":

```
 public List<MyWords> SelectWords(string keyword)
        {

            var myword = (from word in conn.Table<MyWords>()
                          where word.Word1 
                          select word);

            return myword.ToList();


        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
List<MyWords> myWord = conn.Table<MyWords>().Where(x => x.ID >= 10 && x.ID <= 15).ToList();
```

This will create a list of the type `MyWords` with all items in the list having an id between 10 and 15.

One way to think of how this works is the code will go through each item in the data table and determine if it should add it to the list based on what's in the `Where()` method.  The syntax `x =>` essentially assigns the current value being checked in the table to `x`.  Then you can add equality, relational, and conditional statements to the method.  If it returns true it adds the item, otherwise it will skip that item.

Comment: thanks ! can you loo this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44487173/xamarin-forms-sqlite-select-specifics-rows?noredirect=1#comment75968390_44487173