# Xamarin Forms sqlite Select specifics rows

Tags: sqlite, xamarin

I am a novice in Xamarin and I am looking for a way so select specifics rows in my table.

Here is my methode :

```
 public List<MyWords> SelectWords( int rows  , int x )
        {

            if ( x<=6 ) {
                var myword = (from word in conn.Table<MyWords>()
                              where ( word.ID >= 10 && word.ID =< 17 )
                              select word);
                return myword.ToList();
            }
```

This is working but the things  is, if you delete 3 rows which ID is between 10 and 17 ,  you will not get 7 rows but 4  ( (17-10)= 7 and (7-3) =4)  .

So I am looking for a way to get 7 rows even if I delete rows . Or if you know a better solution.

I was thinking , maybe there is a way to refresh my word.ID then this will always work .

thanks

Comment: There are eight rows in the inclusive range 10..17. But how should the extra rows be selected then?

Comment: I was thinking , maybe there is a way to refresh my word.ID then  this will always work

Comment: I think you are confusing Tables and Lists.  When you delete an item from a list, all the members above it will shift down one to fill the gap.  A table, like an array, doesn't shift and simply leaves a gap where the item was.  Attempting to get an object at a deleted reference will simply return null.

Comment: I understand , so do you have an example about  how I can put My table value in a list ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to make it so that you always took the next seven elements after the index ten, you could make your query something like this:

```
return conn.Table<MyWords>().Where(x => x.id >= 10).Take(7).ToList();
```

Keep in mind that if you created a table with 17 items, and then deleted the items with ids 12-16 (5 items) and then added five more items, this would return items with ids 10, 11, 17 - 21.  It doesn't reassign ids